# Images corrupt on local storage after bringing them in from a URL

Tags: java, android

So I have it that when an in-app item is purchased the image they purchased is downloaded onto the phone. Works fine on external storage but I want it on INTERNAL storage. I'm using Picasso to load it into a bitmap then put into a PNG file. I'm not sure why it's getting corrupted along the way on internal storage. When the SD card is perfectly fine. 
Anyone have any ideas why this is happening? Thanks!

```
public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //Internal storage
                String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
                File imageFile = new File(path, "image.png");

                FileOutputStream fos = null;


                //TO SD Storage
                File file = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());

                File fileName = new File(file, "scrone.png");

                if (isSDPresent) {




                    if (!fileName.getName().equals("scrone.png")) {

                        try {

                            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
                            ostream.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else if (fileName.getName().equals("scrone.png")) {
                        try {

                            fileName = new File(file, "scrtwo.png");

                            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
                            ostream.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }




                //I'm sorry for the mess you're about to witness

            else if(!imageFile.exists()){
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "File doesn't exist");

                    fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                    fos.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else if(imageFile.exists())
            {
                try
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "File does exist");
                    imageFile = new File("image2.png");

                    fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, fos);
                    fos.close();
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            }




        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: `createNewFile()` before `new FileOutputStream(...)` is always and everywhere a complete waste of time and space. You are forcing the operating system to delete the file you just created and create a new one. Don't do this. You don't need to test `fileName.getName().equals("scrone.png")` twice. `else` is sufficent.

Comment: Changed that now but it's still corrupted and won't display the image.

Comment: Also I'm looking to add in more than just 2 images, lookking to add multiple so the else if is when I get a third/fourth etc. image in I'll need it.

Comment: `imageFile = new File("image2.png");` should be `imageFile = new File(path, "image2.png");` I think. (Quality 75 is disregarded for PNG.)

Comment: I think that might be it. Thanks, I'll let you know now in a few minutes. And I'll keep that in mind about the quality too.

Comment: @JoopEggen Unfortunately that hasn't fixed it but thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: @ChristopherMckenzie If I thought that was an answer I would have posted it as an answer. It was posted as a comment.